# Generate random integers that has a specific difference from other elements of an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

Hello I am trying to create a classic Rapid Roll game with PyGame.
When I am spawning the bars tho they sometime appear very near to each other which I don't want. I want them have a specific gap in between while having random coordinates.
Here is my problem

[image]

As you can see some blocks are overlapping

I used the following lines of codes for generating random x and y coordinates.

```py
    def generateRandomCoords(self):
        bar_coords = []
        for i in range(self.number):
            bar_x = random.randint(ball_r*2 + bar_w, dimension[0]) - bar_w
            bar_y = random.randint(0, dimension[1]) - bar_h
            bar_coords.append([bar_x, bar_y])
        return bar_coords
```

Comment: Why don't you generate a list of positions on which you can allow to have a new bar then pick one randomly.

Comment: It will still not be random for sure . Player can predict the position.

Comment: No it will be random. Imagine in 1D you have positions from 1 to 10. You have a block in 5 and one in 7. If you want a gap of at least 1 between two blocks, make a list of available slots (here 1,2,3,9,10) and pick one **randomly**. Repeat the process if needed. Exactly want you want I believe.

Comment: what if just the X axis is random? every delta Y you create a new bar, so that there are no bars on the same level. you could skip some levels to increase the difficulty